# Installing WinZip 15.0 with WinZip.wzmul

Tags: winzip, software-activation

I am having a hard time getting my WinZip installation to recognize the WinZip.wzmul Multi-User Registration File.  I am on a Windows XP and have put the WinZip.wzmul inside of C:\Program Files\WinZip.  However, when I start WinZip by going to Start -> WinZip 15.0, it says this copy of WinZip is not yet registered, and that I need an registration/activation code.  This [webpage](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/74/#wzmul) says that the presence of WinZip.wzmul in this folder will convert WinZip to a licensed, registered version but this is not the case in this situation.  Any recommendations? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know if this still holds true, but in the past all you had to do was double click the .wzmul file to register.  I would keep the .wzmul file with the WinZip MSI file on a network share, and after installing WinZip from the MSI, I would double click the .wzmul file and that would complete the registration.

Comment: Hmm I tried double-clicking the .wzmul file, but it just takes me back to the registration page.  I wonder if my .wzmul file is corrupted or something.

Comment: You may be right, check with WinZip support.

Answer (score 1):

[This is from the WinZip KB article](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/74/).

> Customers who purchase a multi-user license will receive a unique
>   WinZip.wzmul registration file which must be copied to a WinZip
>   subfolder in the Windows Common AppData folder. This folder contains
>   application data for all users. For Windows 7 and Windows Vista, a
>   typical path for the WinZip.wzmul file is C:\ProgramData\WinZip. For
>   Windows XP and Windows 2000, a typical path is C:\Documents and
>   Settings\All Users\Application Data\WinZip. The presence of
>   WinZip.wzmul in this folder will convert WinZip to a licensed,
>   registered version.

So, place your WinZip.wzmul file inside **C:\ProgramData\WinZip** and the application should open and recognize its registration status just fine.

Answer (score -1):

You should put it under C:\ProgramData\Winzip instead of Program Files...

Comment: The directory you suggest doesn't exist on Windows XP